# Override default behaviour of right click on Image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have an anchor tag that contains an image. Left click on the image has an existing behavior where as right click has the default browser behavior. For the sake of question, lets say - I need to log some data on right click.

My current code looks something like this -

```
  const handleClick = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>
  ) => {
    if (e.type === 'click' && e?.button === '2') {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('right click');
    }
    if (typeof props.handleClick === 'function') {
      console.log('Handle Click');
      e.stopPropagation();
      props.handleClick();
    }
  };

return (
  <a
     data-testid="cover-image-link"
     className={someName}
     onClick={handleClick}
      >
     <img id='some-id  alt={altText}
            src={imageUrl} />
  </a>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with the code?